# Excel / PowerPoint - Rotating a 3D Model in a remote app

Tags: excel, vba, 3d, powerpoint

If I add a 3D model to my Excel worksheet then I can use code to rotate it ...

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("modGrating").Model3D.IncrementRotationY 10
```

If I have a 3D model in PPT then I can use code to rotate it ...

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("modGrating").Model3D.IncrementRotationY 10
```

However, if I try to rotate a 3D Model in a PPT presentation opened via Excel then it errors ...

```
Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Application
Dim prs As PowerPoint.Presentation
Set ppt = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
With ppt
    .Visible = True
    .WindowState = ppWindowMaximized
    Set prs = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set prs = .Presentations.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\TestFile.pptm", msoFalse, msoTrue, msoTrue)
    On Error GoTo 0
    prs.Slides(1).Shapes("modGrating").Model3D.IncrementRotationY 10
    .Activate
End With
Set prs = Nothing
Set ppt = Nothing
```

The error is "Run-time error '430':" "Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface"

I can do anything else I like to that shape but I can't access the 3D Model format.

Anyone familar with this issue? Is there any way around it?

I have made a couple of example files that demonstrate the issue. Not sure how to attach tehm here though, assuming I can.

It fails the same way on my PC and on my laptop. Both are running the latest versions of MS 365.

Comment: Purely a guess (since I can't insert a 3d model at present), but have you tried moving the `.Activate` line before the line occasioning the error - both app-specific lines indicate that there is no issue when the 'container' is active...

Comment: Hi. Thanks for that. I tried moving the Activate but the error still happens.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.model3dformat  ...  this link says the syntax is different to Excel

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next`  and make sure the next line runs w/o issue. Your code works well with Office 365.

Comment: Hi taller. Does the code work for you? The On Error lines are just in case the testfile is missing. All the testfile has in it is a 3D Model called "modGrating" but (for me) the code crashes when asked to rotate it.

Comment: @user 10186832 - There is an equivalent page for excel (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.model3dformat) and my tests show that Excel can rotatte a model on a woreksheet using the same call (first code example above). As far as I can see the code "should" work.

Comment: @user 10186832 but, I guess if the Apps do have their own variants of these methods, even though they look the same, maybe I need to create an object specifically for a PPT Model3DFormat. Worth an explore. Will have a look at that. Need to hun the registry for the class name I guess.

Comment: Registry search for Model3DFormat came back with nothing. Mujst be a class that only 365 knows about I guess. Tried assigning .Model3D to a variable defined as PowerPoint.Model3DFormat but that fails as well.

Comment: Also tried my variable as an Object and a Variant but same fail. ".Model3D" refuses to allow access IF called from another 365 app. Giving up on doing it via Excel. Instead I can copy the model over to Excel, rotate it there then put it back I guess but makes what I was trying to achieve a lot harder and probably slowly. I expect the 3D Model object model will get sorted out eventually as feels like not quite finished. Thanks all.

Comment: Do you have an example of an Excel `model3D`?

Comment: @Rogue Yes. The code works well with Office 365 on my PC. I insert 3D by Insert>3D models>Stock 3D models.

Comment: @user Yes, not sure how to share the files though? There is an Excel xlsm that opens a PPT pptx. I also have an .pptm that has code to show PPT can rotate an object at all.

Comment: @taller - ok interesting but the key thing is that the object is in a PPT that code in an XLS opens and tries to manipulate the shape. Can you get it wokring as a remote call?

Comment: @Rogue I have posted my testing detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Prior to rotation, make sure to `select` the shape.
- Use `shp` as a `variant` rather than `PowerPoint.Shape` to avoid the `430` error (the root cause is not certain).

```vb
Option Explicit
' Excel VBA code, Early binding PowerPoint 16.0
Public Sub Test3DinPPT()
    Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim prs As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim shp ' As PowerPoint.Shape
    Set ppt = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    'Set ppt = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    With ppt
        .Visible = True
        '    .WindowState = ppWindowMaximized
        Set prs = .Presentations.Open("d:\temp\TestFile.pptx", msoFalse, msoTrue, msoTrue)
        '    Set prs = .ActivePresentation
        Set shp = prs.Slides(1).Shapes("modGrating")
        '    Set shp = prs.Slides(1).Shapes(1)
        shp.Select
        shp.Model3D.IncrementRotationY 50
        '    .Activate
    End With
    Set prs = Nothing
    Set ppt = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for that. I tried suign a Variant for the Model3D object but not the shape..

Comment: Weird it doesn't work unless you split the line up and have a Shape object. I also found I don't need the Select on my simple test at least but I'll bear that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Start a new Excel workbook and save it on the desktop as a .xlsm file.

Open the VBA IDE and add Microsoft PowerPoint as a reference

Add the below code, in a new module

```
Public Sub Test3DinPPT()

Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Application
Dim prs As PowerPoint.Presentation

Set ppt = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

With ppt
    .Visible = True
    .WindowState = ppWindowMaximized
    Set prs = .Presentations.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\TestFile.pptx", msoFalse, msoTrue, msoTrue)
    prs.Slides(1).Shapes("modGrating").Model3D.IncrementRotationY 10
    .Activate
End With

Set prs = Nothing
Set ppt = Nothing

End sub
```

Start a new PowerPoint presentation and clear everything off slide 1. Add a 3D model, anyone will do and name it as modGrating.

Save the file as TestFile.pptx on the desktop (or wherever you put the Excel file).

Close and exit PPT.

Run the Excel code. It should fail on the IncrementRotation line.

To prove that code can work at all, you can add a 3D Model to the Excel worksheet, call it modGrating and run this procedure ...

```
Public Sub RotateGrating()

ActiveSheet.Shapes("modGrating").Model3D.IncrementRotationY 10

End Sub
```

The shape will move a bit